# Set of limits in first uncountable ordinal set

Tags: general-topology

Let $T$ denote the set of limits in $w_1$ (the first uncountable ordinal). For $n\in N$, let $T + n = \left\{t + n|\ t\in T\right\}$. Show that $T + n$ is uncountable. Describe the set $K$ - the intersection of the closures of the sets $T + 1$ and $T + 5$ in $w_1$.

**My attempt from the hint below:** From the hint below, we can form a union of countable many limit ordinals (a_0,a_1,...) which is again countable. Thus there must be points outside of this union, but these points are well-ordered, so there must be a least element b among them. b is also the limit of the union of the limit ordinals. Then again, consider the countable limit ordinals $a0<a1<a2<...<b<...$, and using the same trick again and again, we see that T has infinitely many limit ordinals.

**Comment 2:** can someone please help with the 2nd part of the problem? I still couldn't figure it out:P

Comment: As you have been on MSE for some time now, you should be aware of the proper asking policy. Users are more likely to offer aid if you provide evidence that you have made an attempt in good faith to solve the problem by yourself. In addition, we can offer more targeted aid if you specify previous attempts you have made, as then we may be able to identify where you are struggling. For more on how to ask questions on this site, please visit http://math.stackexchange.com/help/asking.

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote to reopen this. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is pretty clearly homework, rather than giving a full answer let me give some useful hints:

- Before showing that $T+n$ is uncountable, try showing that $T$ is uncountable. If I give you countably many limit ordinals $\alpha_0<\alpha_1<\alpha_2< . . . $, how can you form a limit ordinal which is distinct from all of them (say, bigger than them all)?
- You're interested in the intersection of $\overline{T+1}$ and $\overline{T+5}$. (I'm using the overline to denote "closure".) What is the intersection of $T+1$ and $T+5$, instead?
- So "closure" is important here. Look at some examples. Is $\omega$ in the intersection of the closures? Is $\omega^2$?

Comment: From your hint, I can form a union of countable many limit ordinals (a_0,a_1,...) which is again countable. Thus there must be points outside of this union, but these points are well-ordered, so there must be a least element $b$ among them. $b$ is also the limit ordinals of the union. Then again, consider the countable limit ordinals $a_0<a_1<a_2<...<b<...$, and using the same trick again and again, we see that $T$ has infinitely many limit ordinals. Is this correct?

Comment: can you please help review my proof, which was added to the original post after I tried to absorb your helpful hints?

Comment: I think your proof needs a lot of work - for example it is **not** the case that elements of $T+5$ are limits of elements of $T+1$. In fact, no element of $T+5$ is a limit, at all.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But is my proof for the first part (uncountability) correct? I'm thinking of your hints for the 2nd part, but I seem to arrive that the intersection of $T+1$ and $T+5$ is $T+1$? Can you elaborate on your hint:(

Comment: The intersection of $T+1$ and $T+5$ is $\emptyset$ - there is no ordinal which is both [limit]+1 and [limit]+5! $T$ is uncountable just because, given any *countable* family of limit ordinals $\alpha_0<\alpha_1< . . . \in T$, their supremum is also a limit ordinal, and is again countable, so is in $T$ - so there are more-than-countably many elements of $T$.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. From your elaboration, I got $Cl(T+1)\cap Cl(T+5)=\emptyset$. Is this true?

Comment: No, it's not - what's the first element of $Cl(T+1)-(T+1)$? What about $Cl(T+5)-(T+5)$?

Comment: can anyone please help me solve the 2nd part of the problem above:(